# 2 USB cable stripped wires vs black unstripped wire?

Tags: usb, soldering, ground, shield

[image: 2 wires]

Here is my simple little project ,
I have bought these 2 very long cables, USB cables, but with time the micro USB side which you connect to devices has been damaged on both of them, the USB connector that connects to the adapter then the wall is intact cause that doesn't get used a lot.
I bought them at the length of 2-3meters and 2.1A rating, so they charge fast.

Now I am trying to replace them both with this cheap new micro USB you see on the picture on the right side.

I know everything about the colored wires and how to hook them but I am confused about the stripped wires as what to do with them and why are they different.

One cable doesn't have a black wire, but has one silver, one copper wire.

> Q1:What should I do with those 2 wires?

```
1.braid them together and connect them to the GND pin
2.Connect only copper wire leave the other wire floating
3.Connect only silver wire leave the other wire floating
4.Connect copper wire to the GND pin and the silver to the metal casing on the right of the pins.
5.Connect silver wire to the GND pin and the copper to the metal casing on the right of the pins.
```

the other cable has a black wire and a silver wire.

> Q2:How to connect these 2 wires:

```
1.Connect black wire to GND and leave copper wire floating
2.Connect black wire to GND and connect copper wire to the metal casing on the right of the pins.
```

> Q3: According to the picture drawings what is the actual definition
> name of each part so I can search in Google to understand the
> difference between 1, 2, 3, A, B.

Sorry for being so specific and lengthy but I have seen some other similar questions and the answers are beating around the bush or talking tangentially nobody is giving simple direct responses to the question at hand.
Please if you don't know the answer but you know a lot of theory don't answer and please be specific to what I am asking instead of going on a tangent about something that was not asked.
If you gonna say this project is not worth doing save your words. I am trying to understand and learn I am not trying to make a product for a company so I don't want to hear about edge cases and regulation. Thank you , sorry for maybe sounding like an asshole.

The thing is it seems like a lot of people are getting intoduced to this field because they are trying something similar to this and probably get discouraged by the vague non-answers , so if someone can take some time and use simple words to explain this it will prob help not only me but a lot of other newbies trying out stuff.

Comment: Have you used a DMM to see what the different stripped wires are connected to on the end with the good connector?